# How to create folders from a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, recursion, nested-lists

How to create folders with name of all dictionaries in nested dictionary?
The code should iterate through dictionary and create the directories structure like in nested  dictionary with keeping all hierarchy.

```py
dic = {
    "root": {
        '0_name': {
            "0_name_a": {
                "0_name_a_a": {
                },
                "0_name_a_b": {
                    "file": "file"
                }                
            },
            "0_name_b": {
            }
            
        },
        "1_name": {
        },
        "2_name": {
        },
        "3_name": {
            "3_name": {
                          
            },
            
        }       
    }
}
```

Should make directories like:

```
root/0_name
root/0_name/0_name_a
root/0_name/0_name_a/0_name_a_a
root/0_name/0_name_a/0_name_a_b
root/0_name/0_name_b
root/1_name/1_name_a
root/2_name/
root/3_name/3_name(the same name)
```

The script needs to determine if the value is final, and create a folder with that path, then remove that value from a dictionary and start over. Also somehow to recognize "file" type and skip it. I couldn't determine a recursive way to iterate all values and add them to a path.

My approach (absolutely not working, just pasted it in to show something):

```
def rec(dic):
    path = []
    def nova(dic):
        for k, v in dic.copy().items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                path.append(k)
                if not v: 
                    print(os.path.join(*path))
                    path.clear()
                    dic.pop(k)
                nova(v)
    if path == []:
        nova(dic)
```

Comment: pathlib.Path has a method called mkdir that can make directories.

Comment: What was the script you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need a recursive program, and the value of "path" needs to be part of that recursion.

This isn't exactly what you want, but it's close.

```
def handle_problem(dic):
    def one_directory(dic, path):
        for name, info in dic.items():
            next_path = path + "/" + name
            if isinstance(info, dict):
                print("Creating " + next_path) # actually use mkdir here!
                one_directory(info, next_path)
    one_directory(dic, '')
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much Frank! That's what I wanted! Thanks again!